# Can this group + sum query be written better so it can perform faster?

Tags: postgresql

This is the data:

```
me  friend  game    status  count
1   2       gem     done    10
2   1       gem     done    5
1   3       gem     done    4
3   1       gem     done    6
```

This is my query:

```
WITH
  -- outgoing for all
    outgoing_for_all AS
  (SELECT
     me,
     sum(count) AS sum
   FROM game_totals
   WHERE status IN ('pending', 'done')
   GROUP BY me),

  -- incoming for all
    incoming_for_all AS
  (SELECT
     friend,
     sum(count) AS sum
   FROM game_totals
   WHERE status IN ('pending', 'done')
   GROUP BY friend)

SELECT
  me,
  outgoing_for_all.sum AS outgoing,
  incoming_for_all.sum AS incoming,
  outgoing_for_all.sum - incoming_for_all.sum AS score
FROM outgoing_for_all
  FULL OUTER JOIN incoming_for_all ON outgoing_for_all.me = incoming_for_all.friend
```

This is the result:

```
me  outgoing    incoming    score
1   14          11          3
2   5           10          -5
3   6           4           2
```

Can the query above be written so it will perform faster?
I think there might be possibility to do the summing with just one `SELECT`. The problem is, I don't know how to `GROUP BY` properly so I can sum `count` from two rows into one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is, I don't know how to `GROUP BY` properly so I can sum `count` from two rows into one.

You guessed right: because you want a single row (a `count` value) to be counted twice (one for `me`'s `outgoing` and one for `friend`'s `incoming`), you'll need to double all of your rows. Also, these doubled rows will need to be grouped by a different column. The traditional approach usually is something with `UNION`:

```
SELECT me,
       SUM(count) FILTER (WHERE mul = 1) outgoing,
       SUM(count) FILTER (WHERE mul = -1) incoming,
       SUM(mul * count) score
FROM (
  SELECT me, 1 mul, count
  FROM   game_totals
  WHERE  status IN ('pending', 'done')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT friend, -1, count
  FROM   game_totals
  WHERE  status IN ('pending', 'done')
) t
GROUP BY me;
```

Or, because we know exactly that each row must be counted twice, you can use a `CROSS JOIN` too:

```
SELECT   CASE mul WHEN 1 THEN me ELSE friend END me,
         SUM(count) FILTER (WHERE mul = 1) outgoing,
         SUM(count) FILTER (WHERE mul = -1) incoming,
         SUM(mul * count) score
FROM     game_totals, (VALUES (1), (-1)) m(mul)
WHERE    status IN ('pending', 'done')
GROUP BY CASE mul WHEN 1 THEN me ELSE friend END
```

**BUT**: these are just more readable. They are actually slower than your variant. (I'm afraid, simple window functions won't help you either here.) I think you've already found the fastest solution. However, you should think about using indexes (Maybe more, or other indexes, if you already using them). F.ex. this index could help you a lot:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_game_totals_me_friend_count
  ON game_totals(me, friend, count)
  WHERE status IN ('pending', 'done');
```

http://rextester.com/NGAHW3672

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get sum of both in one query, using [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html).

```
SELECT
 me,
 sum(count) AS sum over(partition by me) AS outgoing,
 sum(count) AS sum over(partition by friend) AS incoming
FROM game_totals
WHERE status IN ('pending', 'done')
```

Comment: It didn't really return the expected result, but it's probably close. I will have to understand window functions first. Thank you for the reference.